# Attempting to install rmarkdown package gives me the error

Tags: r, installation, package, r-markdown, knitr

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.13 is being loaded, but >= 0.15 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/mazen/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/knitr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'knitr' is not available for package 'rmarkdown'
* removing 'C:/Users/mazen/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a more recent version of **xfun**:

```r
install.packages('xfun')
```

However, your R version is too old (3.5.x). With this old version of R, you don't have access to CRAN's prebuilt binary version of **xfun**. Your two choices are:

1. Either upgrade R;
2. or install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Unless you are in a locked environment that prevents you from upgrading R, I strongly recommend that you upgrade R, instead of installing Rtools for an old version of R.

Comment: ah thank u very mush i installed R (3.5.x) cuz our teacher asked u to do so but then i wanted to learn rstudio alone and in a tutorial it asked us to download rmarkdown thx dude

Comment: I don't know why your teacher asked you to use an old version of R. Personally I'd recommend that you install a more recent version.